# Webpack2: как не включать в продакшен-сборку то, что не используется

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, webpack2

Можно ли в `Webpack2` не включать в продакшен сборку переменные, функции и т. д., которые были объявлены, но не были использованы? Судя по всему, по умолчанию он это не делает (и if-блоки, которые всегда верны, тоже не убирает):

```
Side effects in initialization of unused variable widgetsSlider [about.js:25080,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable widgetsSortable [about.js:25814,4] Side effects in initialization of unused variable widgetsSpinner [about.js:27887,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable widgetsTabs [about.js:28793,4]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable widgetsTooltip [about.js:29296,4]

WARNING in feedback.js from UglifyJs
Condition always true [feedback.js:10285,5]
```

В основном это имеет значит для сторонних библиотек. Допустим, я хочу использовать jQueryUI, но не всю, а только небольшую часть её возможностей. Можно, конечно, вручную выбрать то, что надо и скачать это с сайта разработчиков, но, стремясь к рационализации, хотелось бы указать в `dependences` файла `package.json`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1"
  },
```

и добиться того, чтобы в продакшен-сборку был включен только тот функционал библиотеки, который действительно используется. Можно ли этого добиться?

Повторюсь, что данный вопрос имеет отношение к `Webpack2.x.x`, а не к первой depricated-серии.

Comment: Посмотрел `jquery-ui-dist`, увы не получится так сделать (он уже идет как собранный компонент). Приведу пример например с `react-bootstrap` - если вы подключаете так: `import {Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap` вы получите весь пакет react-bootstrap с ненужными для вас остальными компонентами, но вы можете сделать лучше (и правильней) это подключать их так: import Row from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Row' (там идет либо /lib/ либо /es/). IDE поддерживает и тот и тот импорт и тогда у вас попадут только нужные поля.

Comment: Понятно, а если скачать вручную только нужные компоненты `jQuery-UI`, то тогда можно не указывать в `package.json` данную зависимость?

Comment: у них внутренняя зависимость сильная, сложно реализовать, а в чем проблема подключить всю библиотеку? вынести её при сборки в `vendor` и забыть?

Comment: В том, что выходной файл получится очень большой (даже минифицированный). В него будет входить `jQuery`, `jQueryUI` + свои скрипты. Большую часть займёт именно `jQueryUI`, потому что её функционал очень солидный. А про вынов в `vendor`, пожалуйста, поподробнее (впервые слышу).

Comment: ну у вас все что внешнее подгружаемое из node_modules попадет например в файл `vendor.js`, а ваш клиентский код в отдельный например `main.js`, дебажить легче (консоль открывает заведомо меньший файл с меньшим количеством строк и без мусора) ну и само по себе разделение https://medium.com/@adamrackis/vendor-and-code-splitting-in-webpack-2-6376358f1923 читайте с `Breaking up our main bundle`

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!